# How to combine these three tables into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have trhee table

1. [PKS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL6sm.png)

| Satker | PKS |
| --- | --- |
| FIK | 2 |
| FT | 2 |

2. [IA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ltN9.png)

| Satker | IA |
| --- | --- |
| FIK | 1 |
| FT | 2 |

3. [MOU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3s8J.png)

| Satker | MOU |
| --- | --- |
| FIK | 3 |

I want to combine the trhee of it into one table like this 
[Combined table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2kIb.png)

| Satker | PKS | IA | MOU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| FIK | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| FT | 2 | 2 |  |

How can i do that ?, i already try left join but the result is not what i expected.

```
SELECT pks.satuan_kerja, count(pks.satuan_kerja) AS PKS, count(pelaksanaan_kerjasama.satuan_kerja) AS IA, count(mou.subsatker_mou) AS MOU
FROM pks
LEFT JOIN pelaksanaan_kerjasama
ON pks.satuan_kerja = pelaksanaan_kerjasama.satuan_kerja
LEFT JOIN mou
ON pks.satuan_kerja = mou.subsatker_mou
GROUP BY pks.satuan_kerja
```

Comment: You possibly can't do serious work without any primary key. Is there any primary key in tables?  Please share table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
CREATE TABLE PKS_tbl          (
             Satker varchar(9),
               PKS int(4)     );
    
INSERT INTO PKS_tbl VALUES('FIK',2), ('FT',2);
   
CREATE TABLE IA_tbl          (
             Satker varchar(9),
             IA int(4)       );
 
INSERT INTO IA_tbl VALUES('FIK',1), ('FT',2);

CREATE TABLE MOU_tbl    (
            Satker varchar(9),
            MOU int(4)  );   

INSERT INTO MOU_tbl VALUES('FIK',3);


select p.Satker,
       PKS,
       i.IA,
       m.MOU
from PKS_tbl p 
inner join
(
select Satker, IA from IA_tbl ) as i on p.Satker=i.Satker
left join
(select Satker, MOU from MOU_tbl ) as m on p.Satker=m.Satker ;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/111